# Run ScalaTest tests (not suites) in parallel in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'd like to run all the tests of a particular suite in parallel. Apparently I can do that by mixing the [`ParallelTestExecution`](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.9.1/index.html#org.scalatest.ParallelTestExecution) trait into my suite, but the tests keep being run in order. I suspect that this is because a `Distributor` is not being passed to `runTests`. Looking on the the scalatest-users mailing list, it appears that this is a known issue that will be [fixed in sbt 0.13 and ScalaTest's associated release](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalatest-users/IE68DyT8My0/JhgN4AxbquQJ).

Is this correct?